# How to type pinyin on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I type these characters on iOS: ǎ ě ǐ ǒ ǔ ǚ

It would be best if I can add these to my normal keyboard (English UK), e.g. enable long-pressing on the vowel like normal to bring up the options

But so far I haven't been able to find any way at all to simply type pinyin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate the Simplified Chinese Pinyin keyboard.  Long pressing the letters on that one should give you the 4 tone options.  Also I think there are 3rd party keyboards in the app store.

You can't modify the English UK or other keyboards supplied by Apple.

Comment: Yep, and then I have to press the 换行 or 空格 button to prevent it turning into characters

Comment: @theonlygusti  that should only be necessary on  words with no tone mark, right?